# No overload matches this call Error while using css-in-js in Typescript, Webpack, React Project

Tags: css, reactjs, typescript, webpack

I have Webpack, Typescript, and React Hooks project in which I am using CSS-in-js to pass styling to a div.  I am getting the following error when I hover over the `style` prop in the `Menu` component. I am not sure where shall I bind the CSSProperties.

```
(JSX attribute) React.HTMLAttributes<HTMLDivElement>.style?: React.CSSProperties
Type '{ display: string; margin: number; padding: number; alignItems: string; flexDirection: string; justifyContent: string; width: string; height: string; background: string; }' is not assignable to type 'CSSProperties'.
  Types of property 'flexDirection' are incompatible.
    Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'FlexDirection'.ts(2322)
index.d.ts(1768, 9): The expected type comes from property 'style' which is declared here on type 'DetailedHTMLProps<HTMLAttributes<HTMLDivElement>, HTMLDivElement>'
```

Menu Component:

```js
import React from 'react';

const Menu = () => (
    <div maxWidth="lg" style={styles.menuContainer}>
        MENU COMPONENT
    </div>
)

export default Menu;

const styles = {
    menuContainer: {
        display: 'flex',
        margin: 0,
        padding: 0,
        alignItems: 'center',
        flexDirection: 'row',
        justifyContent: 'space-around',
        width: '100%',
        height: '5vh',
        background: 'rgba(212, 15, 24,0.8)',
    }
};
```

tsconfig.json:

```json
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "outDir": "./public",
        "noImplicitAny": true,
        "module": "AMD",
        "target": "es6",
        "jsx": "react",
        "allowJs": true,
        "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "esModuleInterop": true
    },
    "include": [ "src", "image.d.ts" ],
    "exclude": [ "node_modules", "**/*.spec.ts" ]
}
```

Comment: If i replace css-in-js with inline styling style={{border: '1px solid red'}} , TS Compiler does not throw any error.

Comment: Following works :- export const styles:React.CSSProperties = {
    display: "flex"
};   What I am looking for is creating different styled objects inside styles properties like outerContainer, innerContainer which is not working.

Answer (score 0):

There's a difference between the following two:

```js
<Component style={{ flexDirection: 'row' }} />
// compared to
const style = { flexDirection: 'row' };
<Component style={{ flexDirection: 'row' }} />;
```

According to the typings behind the `style` prop, which is a `React.CSSProperties`, it expects `flexDirection` to be of type `FlexDirection`, which is an union type of `'row' | 'column' | ...`.

In the first case, TypeScript is smart enough to realize that you're trying to construct a `React.CSSProperties` and therefore it goes "we expect one of those string values, and `'row'` is one of them, good".

In the second case, when you pre-define the object, TypeScript performs [type widening](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-1.html#better-inference-for-literal-types) and basically thinks `flexDirection` is just meant to be a string. *Which is usually the case, which is why it's the default interpretation.* But when you then pass this value to `style`, it now sees your object's `flexDirection` as a `string` instead of the `'row'` constant.

---

The most developer-friendly solution I've come up with over the years (both my friends and I stumbled upon this issue at times, although not always regarding React) is using a kind of generic helper function:

```js
// Using this as example, but you can directly use React.CSSProperties
// (or really any other type that benefits from this "pattern" below)
interface CSSProperties {
    flexDirection?: 'row' | 'column';
}

// This simply returns the object itself, but we benefit from the special typing.
// As for the cost of a single simple function call? Negligible and worth it.
function checkStylesheets<T extends { [key in keyof T]: CSSProperties }>(obj: T): T {
    return obj;
}

// To showcase the original problem: TypeScript sees 'row' as just a string
const widenedStyle = { flexDirection: 'row' };
// typeof widenedStyle = { flexDirection: string }

const styles = checkStylesheets({
    menuContainer: {
        flexDirection: 'row',
    },
    unknownProperty: {
        // Type '{ nonExistingField: number; }' is not assignable to type 'CSSProperties'.
        // Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'nonExistingField' does not exist in type 'CSSProperties'.ts(2322)
        nonExistingField: 123,
    },
    invalidFlexDirection: {
        // Type '"invalid"' is not assignable to type '"row" | "column" | undefined'.ts(2322)
        flexDirection: 'invalid',
    },
    notEvenAString: {
        // Type 'number' is not assignable to type '"row" | "column" | undefined'.ts(2322)
        flexDirection: 5,
    }
});
// typeof styles = {
//     menuContainer: CSSProperties;
//     unknownProperty: CSSProperties;
//     invalidFlexDirection: CSSProperties;
//     notEvenAString: CSSProperties;
// }

const someStyle: CSSProperties = styles.menuContainer;
// Property 'nonExistingName' does not exist on type '{ menuContainer: CSSProperties; unknownProperty: CSSProperties; invalidFlexDirection: CSSProperties; notEvenAString: CSSProperties; }'.ts(2339)
const anotherStyle: CSSProperties = styles.nonExistingName;
```

*simplified the example with a custom `CSSProperties` interface*

The above solution/example lists some of the resulting styles in the comments, along with all the TypeScript errors it produces.

**Q**: Why the need for a helper function? Why not simply set or cast the type of `styles` to `Record<string, CSSProperties>` or similar?

**A**: By using this trick, `checkStylesheets` will validate that the passed object fits the requirement of being an object with only `CSSProperties` fields. But because of the generic nature with `keyof T`, it will the object with the same keys, but as values `CSSProperties`.

The main benefot of this is that **`styles` keeps its keys**. Which means TypeScript will warn us for e.g. `styles.nonExistingStyle`, very handy for having intellisense and spotting typos. Especially since the `style` prop accepts `undefined`!

**Q**: Can't we just do `const styles = { ... } as const;` instead?

**A**: Yes, that'll work, but TypeScript won't validate your styles until you actually pass the object to the `style` prop. At that point, the `style` prop will complain, while with the above solution, TypeScript would already warn you when defining `styles`, regardless of whether you use it or not. *There's also the fact that `styles`'s type will be a very complex object where intellisense (and TypeScript errors) will take up your whole screen once you have several (non-tiny) styles in your object. Very different from a simple `{ styleA: CSSProperties; styleB: CSSProperties; ... }`.*

**Q**: Can't we just do `const styles: { styleA: CSSProperties } = { styleA: {...} };`?

**A**: Yes, that'll work just as well, but it's double work. It's a completely fine solution, now it just depends on which coding style you prefer. This even has the advantage of defining the type of `styles` separately (e.g. as an interface) if you prefer seeing e.g. `const styles = MyStyles` instead of `const styles = { styleA: CSSProperties; ... }` in intellisense.